# Select all checboxes after selecting the first one

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few checkboxes, and I want all the others to be checked as well, after selecting the first one. Why is this code not working correctly?

```
var del = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="del_id[]"]');

del.forEach(function(elem){
   elem.addEventListener('input',function(){
      if(del[0].checked){
         elem.checked = true;
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: please add html code portion also.

Comment: It is generated in php. This is the first checkbox in table th, and the rest of the chechboxes are at each row.

Comment: It has, because checking e.g. console.log inside works.

Comment: Each input has its own even listener that checks itself. try something like `del.forEach(i => i.check = true)` instead of `elem.check = true` and the event listener should only be needed on the first input and not all of them.

Comment: @yifansong Your code is working! Thanks!